# Java Array index check

Tags: java, arrays

I have an int array and I have assigned a value from it with a random index to a int variable. I wanted to know if there is a way to check the index from the array that it came from from the variable it was assigned.

```
Random rand = new Random();

private int[] cards = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

int a = cards[rand.nextInt(8)];
```

so I assigned a value from the array to variable a but I want to know if there is a way to check the variable a to see what the index was it came from

Comment: Just store your `rand.nextInt(8)` in an own variable, then you know your index ... quite obvious, right?

Comment: Very simple question. Though i have answered it but still the user has not given a thought before questioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the value of random before the use.

```
int randomValue = rand.nextInt(8);
int a = cards[randomValue];
```

Comment: thanks this helps... I'm somewhat new to Java and am creating a blackjack program for a class project. this was a scaled down version I posted here and my array has a total of 52 index's and some share the same value so the search option didn't really suit what I was doing. I'm sure there are much more efficient methods of doing what my program is attempting to do but this helps a lot... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You know the index number as you are already getting the value in the index position of the array.

> int index = rand.nextInt(8);

It is always advised to use ArrayList. And if you had used that there is an easy method called "indexOf" to find out the index of the value in the list.

Comment: To be precise `indexOf` doesn't tell you where your element comes from, it just tells you where an "equal" instance (according to the `equals` implementation) is placed in the list. It could still be a different instance.

Comment: Sorry i did not get what you saying. But, say you have a value and you want to know the index of it, then `indexOf` function from `ArrayList` gives you that choice.

Comment: `indexOf` returns the first index where an _equal_ object is located and _equal_ is determined by the `equals` implementation. So this method might not return the index of the instance you're looking. For example: `String a = new String("a"); String b = new String("a"); List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a, b)); System.out.println(l.indexOf(b));`. This prints *"0"*, because on index 0 there is an _equal_ instance, but is refers to a different object in the memory and is therefore not the one you're looking for, just a "similar" one.

Comment: This is not a problem, if you have unique values in your list or (boxed) primitive types, but one should mind that detail.

Comment: Absolutely right tom, but here we have integers so much details are not kept in mind. We can implement equals method if we want to compare Objects. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int index= rand.nextInt(8);
int a = cards[index];
```

Answer (score -1):

With a simple array, you have to iterate to find out what position a given value is in.
For example:

```
int findSlot(int a)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = cards.length; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (cards[i] == a) return i;
    }
}
```

However, if you use an ArrayList, you can make use of the method indexOf().

As noted by other folks who've answered, the index returned (in both cases) will be the first matching instance.